# How to store functions with `impl type` returns in a vector?

Tags: rust

How would one make a vector of function points that contain an impl type result?

The only way I could find is to create an intermediate closure that does transform it to a concrete type. What alternatives do we have to create this vector, assuming we could not change the signature of the `example` function?

```rs
struct Resp {}

trait Responsable {
    fn to_resp(&self) -> Resp;
}

impl Responsable for Resp {
    fn to_resp(&self) -> Resp {
        Resp {}
    }
}

fn example() -> impl Responsable {
    Resp {}
}

fn foo() {
    let mut vector: Vec<fn() -> Resp> = Vec::new();
    vector.push(|| example().to_resp());

   // Is there a way to use dyn / impl in the vector type without
   // changing the signature of the example function?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-> impl Responsable` creates an anonymous type for that return value. You can create a `Vec` of that anonymous type, as long as you do not have to name it anywhere:

```
fn foo() {
    let mut vector = Vec::new();
    vector.push(example());
    vector.push(example());
```

If you want, you can name the type of the vector, with `let mut vector: Vec<_>;`.

That is of limited usability, as you cannot mix different anonymous types, even if they look the same:

```
fn example() -> impl Responsable {
    Resp {}
}
fn example_2() -> impl Responsable {
    Resp {}
}

fn foo() {
    let mut vector = Vec::new();
    vector.push(example());
    vector.push(example_2()); // Error! what is the type of `vector`?
}
```

If you need an heterogeneous vector, then you can use type erasure and dynamic dispatch:

```
fn foo() {
    let mut vector: Vec<&dyn Responsable> = Vec::new();
    let e = example();
    vector.push(&e);
    let e = example_2();
    vector.push(&e);
}
```

In this case you need to declare the type of the `Vec` or do a cast to the `&dyn` reference at least once, the compiler will not do it by itself.
Also, you need to keep the values in a local variable, as the `Vec` is holding references, and those references must point somewhere.

Finally, if you want the `Vec` to be `'static` and not have references, you can box the values. This is the most flexible solution, but it has extra allocations:

```
fn foo() -> Vec<Box<dyn Responsable>> {
    let mut vector: Vec<Box<dyn Responsable>> = Vec::new();
    vector.push(Box::new(example()));
    vector.push(Box::new(example_2()));

    // Now you can even return the vector!
    vector
}
```

---

On second read, I think you want to store in the `Vec` the functions themselves, not the result of calling them. The easiest way to do that is going the `Box` way and doing your closure trick:

```
fn foo()  {
    let mut vector: Vec<fn() -> Box<dyn Responsable>> = Vec::new();
    vector.push(|| Box::new(example()));
    vector.push(|| Box::new(example_2()));
}
```